# Apache: Errors AH00557 and AH00558 don't get away and PHP not working

Tags: php, apache

1.) If I start apache I get these errors:

`AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Macintosh-3.local`

`AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

I have already set `ServerName` to `localhost` in the `httpd.conf` file.
But unfortunately the errors don't get away.

2.) I have removed the `#` before the PHP module in the `httpd.conf` file. But if I load a `.php` file it just shows me the code.

Comment: Read on php.net how to setup PHP in Apache.  After you activate the module, you have to define which file extentions will be processed by the PHP module.

Comment: I've followed all the steps on php.net. But it still doesn't work. Another weird thing is that I have set my document root to `/Library/WebServer/Documents` but it only takes files out of `/usr/local/var/www`

Comment: You will have to post your httpd.conf file for us to figure it out.  You might have configurations in a VirtualHost what overwrides the general directives you set in your global file (ex. httpd.conf defines DocumentRoot, but you include extra/httpd_vhosts.conf which redefines it for *:80 connections).

Comment: Here is my httpd.conf file: https://pastebin.com/YuKY7rQR

Comment: I believe it's a warning not an error

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have fixed it myself by reinstalling everything :)